# How to watch for changes to a object in AngularJS from a controller?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming I have an object in the rootScope:

```
$scope.mydict = {
  'apple': {'properties':{'color':'red', 'texture': 'mm'}, 'physics': {'bouncy': 'no', 'impact': 'breaks'}},
  'pear': {'properties':{'color':'red', 'texture': 'mm'}, 'physics': {'bouncy': 'no', 'impact': 'breaks'}}
}
```

Assuming depending on how the user interacts, this $scope may have more and more fruits indicated by the key. How would I be able to $watch for changes to the dictionary for any new items that are added and process them?

I tried:

```
$watch("mydict" ...)
```

Though it complains about mydict not being there and doesnt seem to allow me to watch dictionaries. **Note that the $scope.mydict is initialized by another service i defined to get the resource from to populate that variable in the $scope, so it might not exist in the directive that is responsible for $watch-ing the data changing.**

What I want to do is for every new fruit that gets added to "mydict", output the "properties.texture" of ONLY that item. If it is possible to watch and see if any new frutis added even have a "properties.texture" before doing anything(i.e. alert), that would be even better. Though I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Pass true as the third param to watch to get deep watching.

Comment: Like @aet said: `$scope.$watch('mydict', function(newval, oldval) { ... }, true);`

Comment: Is this safe even though 'mydict' may not exist until the service retrieves the $resource? If not, what is the syntactic way to get around it?

Comment: Should be safe, just be aware that your handler-function might be called with null/undefined (can't rememeber which) during initialization.